# Typescript compiler missing ECMAScript 5 support when I am targeting ES6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, tsc

This is my tsconfig.json file: (which it is reading, since the previous errors missing 'async' were resolved by adding it)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es6","dom" ]
  }
}
```

but I am getting errors like:

```
src\main.ts(85,20): error TS2494: Using a string in a 'for...of' statement is only supported in ECMAScript 5 and higher.
src\main.ts(88,38): error TS2569: Type '""' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.
```

Neither the spread operator, or using for..in on a string will work:

```
  var alphas:string[]; 
  const text = "cABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  for (const char of text) {
    alphas.push(char);
  }
  
  const availableGlyphs:string[] = [...'cABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']; 
  const glyph = availableGlyphs[Math.floor(Math.random()*availableGlyphs.length)];
```

Comment: Please also add the code which throws the error

Comment: What is the target ?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Did you miss it? In the title 'targeting ES6' and in the text it says  "lib": [ "es6","dom" ]

Comment: By adding the `es6` library your code is not compiled to es6.

Comment: `lib` is not the same thing as `target`. Those are two separate config options

Answer (score -1):

**Edit** actually the real problem was that I was mixing up `lib` and `target` (thanks @ritaj). The straightforward solution was to do this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "target": "es6",
...
```